# Best way to place two html sections side by side

Tags: html

1. Summarize the problem

The purpose of this question is to find the best way to display two sections of html side by side. Ideally, I'd like to be able to break the UI up like so

[image]

Rather than the current setup

[image]

2. Describe what you’ve tried

I've tried modifying the html on my own, but I would like to get advice from a more experienced develop on how to do this.

3. Show some code

```
<center>
        <div id="boxstyle">
          <h3 id="h3style">Section 5.2 Word Matching Exercise</h3>

          <center>
            <div class="inputBoxes">
              User Input:
              <table id="tablestyle">
                <td>
                  <input id="el1" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="el2" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="el3" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="el4" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="el5" type="text" value="">
                </td>
              </table>
            </div>
          </center>
          <center>
            <div class="inputBoxes">
              Result in HTML:
              <table id="tablestyle">
                <td>
                  <input id="dl1" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="dl2" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="dl3" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="dl4" type="text" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="dl5" type="text" value="">
                </td>
              </table>
              <span style="padding: 3px">
                <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="process_input()">generate html</button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </center>
          <center>
```

Comment: Both ```flexbox``` and ```grid``` would work for this!

Comment: Note that the `<center>` tag has been obsolete for many years. Do not use it.

Comment: Stacking elements one after the other is the typical HTML behaviour. To modify it, you must use styling. You can copy&paste an answer from here, but I think you are missing the basic of HTML programming. I would advise you to read some tutorial like this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout. It will save you time in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to learn `CSS Flexbox`. For example:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.column-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.column-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column column-2">Colum 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` for this. 
The all the inputs are enclosed within `inputBoxes` where `display:flex;`. The `center` tag is not used anymore so `justify-content: center;` was used to align the flex boxes. Similiarly all the text was aligned to the center using  `text-align: center;`

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "boxstyle">
         <h3 id="h3style">Section 5.2 Word Matching Exercise</h3>
         User Input:
         <div class="inputBoxes">
              <div><input id="el1" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="el2" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="el3" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="el4" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="el5" type="text" value=""></div>
         </div>
        
          Result in HTML :
         <div class="inputBoxes">
              <div><input id="dl1" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="dl2" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="dl3" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="dl4" type="text" value=""></div>
              <div><input id="dl5" type="text" value=""></div>
         </div>
         <span style="padding: 3px">
                <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="process_input()">generate html</button>
         </span>
    </div>
</body>


<style>
body{ 
    text-align: center;
    }
.inputBoxes{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.inputBoxes div{
    margin-left: 2%;
}

</style>
</html>
```